# Possessives - "this year's question paper" or "this year question paper"

Tags: possessives

I found this in a grammar book:

> Wrong Sentence - All the candidates felt that **this year's question paper** was too easy.
>
> Right Sentence - All the candidates felt that **this year the question paper** was too easy.

Is "this year's question paper" really wrong, and if so, why? What makes "this year the question paper" better?

Is there a rule here about constructing possessive sentences?

Comment: *Why* do you think the first version is "wrong"?

Comment: I don't. I found this in a grammar book.And the book does..I was really confused because I couldn't find any error..

Comment: I can't imagine why any "grammar book" should say that - but it's complete rubbish, so I'd suggest you disregard *everything* in that book, or you may end up knowing *less* than you currently do, rather than *more*.

Comment: Please, what is the grammar book? Is it the same grammar book which you referred to [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20228/32)?

Comment: Yes both questions are from the same book..

Comment: What is the title, and who is the author?

Comment: It's Objective General English by DR.R.S and Vikas Aggarwal.

Comment: What reasoning does the book give?

Comment: it didn't explain or hadn't given any reason why.

Comment: @TzD Avoid trusting the books written by non-native speakers. And you can **buy** my words on this! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are many books' content I have come across in India written by local authors that's difficult to believe!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> All the candidates felt that this year's question paper was too easy.

There is nothing wrong with this sentence as it stands. *This year's question paper* is an ordinary noun phrase, with *this year's* acting as its determiner. That is idiomatic in even the most formal writing: *this year's paper* is the paper in use this year.

> All the candidates felt that this year the question paper was too easy.

There is nothing wrong with this sentence, either, but it is not in any way superior to the first sentence. The difference is that *this year* is deployed as a modifier to the entire subordinate clause rather than just its subject. That means that *paper* now lacks a determiner, which is supplied with *the*.

There is, by the way, no such thing as a 'possessive sentence'. Nouns and pronouns may be possessive, but not sentences.

Comment: I edited the last examples but I'm still a bit confused about how *this year's question paper* is equal to *this year the question paper*. It's entirely different I feel.

Comment: @MaulikV The two *are* different - I define the difference above. In one, *this year's* identifies **which** paper is too easy. In the other, *this year* tells **when** a particular paper is too easy. You infer that the same paper is meant in both instances; but the sentences do not express that. Just for instance: the second sentence might mean "We have set the same paper every year, but this year we have such outstanding candidates that it is too easy; they will all score 100% and we will not be able to declare a winner."

Comment: I have noticed many in your answers you talked about non idiomatic English.I don't understand what do you mean by idiomatically unexceptionable..And where can I find more about that??

Comment: @StoneyB I hesitated to answer this question the first time I read it, because I couldn't find its flaw. I suspect that it's probably something akin to the rules (guidelines) that suggests ELL to avoid phrases such as "today's news" even though they're perfectly fine. -- For TzD: I read "idiomatically unexceptionable" as "fine, idiomatically"; maybe even better than just "fine (idiomatically)".

Comment: @DamkerngT. Why on earth do they do so? I can see no reason to do so, except as a 'baby rule' to forestall common novice errors - and this quiz item seems to be for students too advanced for that rule to be called upon.

Comment: @TzD I have edited to clarify.

Comment: So if this is true can I also use two possessive noun or pronoun consecutively like this example "I do not like Sam's Brother's attitude"??

Comment: @TzD Absolutely, yes. In theory you can extend it indefinitely, but *Sam's brother's wife's aunt's granddaughter's cat's kitten's dish* will at some point lose your reader :)

Answer (score 0):

> All the candidates felt that this year's question paper was too easy - it's too general. Which question paper of this year? It could be any question paper of this year (Math, Economics, Science, Social Studies...).

And,

> All the candidates felt that this year **the** question paper was too easy - makes better sense as they are talking about **one particular** paper (Math) of this year.

Even if there's **only** one paper in the year, it's better to use **the** as it ensures about *that particular paper.*

We can *generally* drop the article *the* if talking about the thing in general. Adding the definite article will emphasize that you are talking about that particular thing.

For example,

> To think about the happiness of people (i.e., people in general) was important to him (no article). 
>  
>  To think about the people's happiness was important to him (with article, the people of nation/society etc.).

Comment: With a possessive (this year's, people's), however, the definite article is prohibited: the possessive acts as a definite determiner, so a definite article is superfluous. *The people's happiness* is permissible only if you are speaking of the happiness of *the* people, not of people in general.

Comment: @StoneyB But where did you find these in my answer? Am I missing something?

Comment: *This year's paper* talks about a particular paper in the same way and to the same degree as *the paper* does. And in your final sentence, ***the** people* does not mean a particular group of persons -- it means ***all** the people*, the nation or electorate or population considered as a whole.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think you're mistaken about ***the** people* there. Without the article, *thinking about people's happiness* just means *people in general, **all** people*. But when it's included, this almost certainly implies ***some subset of "all" people*** (as Maulik says, the particular nation/society/tribe relevant to the context).